# splunk replace the word in subsearch

Tags: sql, splunk, splunk-query

I have a search contains lots of subsearchs ,and they are in the same format like

```
| union 
    [| search index=idx_dash 
     | spath Data.AA{} AA
     | mvexpand AA | eval _raw=AA
     | spath Key output=Key | spath Value output=Value | where Key="**aaa**" 
     | rex mode=sed field=Value "s/\+/e+/g" | eval Value=tonumber(Value)
     | xyseries Key Value
     | eval **"Aa"** = 'aa' ]
    [| search index=idx_dash 
     | spath Data.BB{} BB
     | mvexpand BB | eval _raw=BB
     | spath Key output=Key | spath Value output=Value | where Key="**bbb**" 
     | rex mode=sed field=Value "s/\+/e+/g" | eval Value=tonumber(Value)
     | xyseries Key Value
     | eval **"Bb"** = 'bb' ]
```

Is there any way to replace the keyword in the subsearch ,so that I can use one subsearch to make it useful? thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro with the keyword as an argument.  The macro might look like this:

```
search index=idx_dash 
| spath Data.$arg1${} $arg1$
| mvexpand $arg1$ 
| eval _raw=$arg1$
| spath Key output=Key 
| spath Value output=Value 
| where Key="**$arg2$**" 
| rex mode=sed field=Value "s/\+/e+/g" 
| eval Value=tonumber(Value)
| xyseries Key Value
| eval **"$arg3$"** = '$arg4$'
```

Then the code would look something like this:

```
| union
  [ | `mymacro("AA","aaa", "Aa", "aa")` ]
  [ | `mymacro("BB","bbb", "Bb", "bb")` ]
```